# How To Check Disabled Property on HTML Select Exist Or Not?

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML structure, it's simplified version of real codes :

```
<div id="kurir_list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select disabled class="tarif">
                ...
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select disabled class="tarif">
                ...
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select disabled class="tarif">
                ...
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`disabled` property of each select are dynamically removed based on other conditional. now, I need to check if there's `disabled` property on each `.tarif` under `#kurir_list` or not using jquery. I have this code, but still can't check whether disabled `.tarif` exist or not :

```
$(".tarif").change(function() {
    if ( !$("#kurir_list.tarif").attr("disabled").length ) {
        $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .next').show();
    }                       
});
```

Comment: `$(element).is(':disabled');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$(".tarif").change(function() {
    if (this).prop("disabled", true)
{
 $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .next').show();
    }                       
});
```